# how would you translate the following ternary operator to regular if statements?

Tags: java

Im reading some code, and I encountered the following ternary expression. how would you translate the following ternary operator to regular if statements?

```
 ( (vowel) ? ((consonant) ? "ay" : "yay") : "")
```

Comment: This is an expression, not a statement.

Comment: @TedHopp whats the difference?

Comment: Most expressions are not legal statements. Note that all the answers (so far) involve using the `return` statement. If you don't want to return the value of the expression, you'll need somewhere to store the value when you turn it into a statement.

Comment: Expression: Something which evaluates to a value. ex: `a+b` .
Statement: A line of code which does something. ex: `c=a+b;`

Comment: I'm curious--what was the obstacle to figuring this out yourself? I think about reasoning about code and I'm wondering where the barrier was. To me it seems like simple de-construction.

Comment: @DaveNewton i looked up  ternary operator as `<condition> ? <result 1> : <result 2>`, but i haven't seen a nested ternary operator, so i wanna make sure i did not misunderstand it...

Comment: @user133466 Work from the inside out as with any complex expression: play parser. What would get evaluated in what order? In this case it's even easier because of the explicit parens.

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks! Tenner hinted the same approach in understanding nested ternary operators, now i understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this:

```
if(vowel) {
    if(consonant) {
        return "ay"
    } else {
        return "yay"
    }
} else {
    return ""
}
```

Note that I'm using `return` because ternary operator is an expression while `if` is a statement in Java, thus it doesn't have a value. You must wrap this in a method returning `String`.

Answer (score 1):

Work from the inside out.

```
if (vowel) {
    if (consonant) {
        return "ay";
    } else {
        return "yay";
    }
} else {
    return "";
}
```

I'd guess the original code is somehow wrong. `vowel` and `consonant` are boolean expressions, and (if I'm guessing at what the code is doing correctly) semantically a letter can't be both a vowel and a consonant. That is, the `"ay"` case won't be called.

Comment: It can, this is checking for `y`.

Answer (score 1):

It translates to:

```
 String result = "";
    if (vowel) {
        if (consonant) {
            result = "ay";
        } else {
            result = "yay";
        }
    } else {
        result = "";
    }
```

Comment: In this else is not required. You have already set result to empty string, so why would you need to reset to empty string again... :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this conveys the intent better than nested ifs:

```
String str = "";
if(vowel && consonant) {
    str = "ay";
} else if(vowel) {
    str = "yay"
}
```

Comment: Nested `if`, chained `if`...potayto, potahto. But +1 for not using a `return` statement.

Answer (score 1):

it will be like this

```
String ans = null;
if(vowel)
        {
            if(consonant)
            {
                ans="ay";
            }
            else
            {
                ans="yay";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ans="";
        }
```

Comment: This isn't legal syntax. A string expression is not a statement.

Comment: @TedHopp - i have updated it .

Answer (score 1):

Except for the () around the conditions, (vowel) and (consonant), replace

```
"(" by "if"
"?" by "{"
":" by "} else {"
")" by "}"
```

and you'll get:

```
if (vowel) { if (consonant) { "ay" } else { "yay" } } else { "" }
```

which if you run it through a beautifier or just add your own typical indenting becomes:

```
if (vowel) {
   if (consonant) {
      "ay"
   } else {
      "yay"
   }
} else {
   ""
}
```

Comment: _run it through a beautifier_ ... and end up with something that isn't legal syntax.

Comment: @TedHopp: Legal syntax for what? The originally posted ternary expression wasn't "legal syntax", the OP just wanted to know what it meant so I showed him how to figure it out. How to use that information in the context of a program as "legal syntax" depends entirely on the context in which the original ternary expression is used.

Comment: @TedHopp: I see some of the other answers assume the OP was using his ternary expression in the context of a return, while others assume it's in the context of an assignment so maybe that's what you're referring to. He could also be using it in the context of a print and there are probably other alternatives. I just assumed the OP could figure out where to put the print, return, assignment, whatever once the ternary expression was broken down for him.

Comment: Not quite - the original code isn't a legal statement, but it's a legal expression.  This isn't legal anything.

Comment: I think Dmitri hit it on the head. OP's code might be found somewhere in a valid Java program. Your's could never be. The array of contexts assumed in the other answers is a consequence of what I noted in my comment to OP's question. With a few exceptions (assignment, non-void function call, pre/post-increment/decrement, etc.), expressions and statements are different beasts.

Comment: You can't convert an out-of-context ternary expression to an "if" statement as the OP requested in "legal syntax". You can make a guess at what the OP wanted and then clutter up your answer with declarations of types or return statements or whatever but in reality whatever context you guess at is probably wrong (since that's just one of N possibilities) and it's trivial for the OP to tweak the pseudo-code I posted to whatever suits his real situation so it's pointless to clutter and obscure _the answer to the question_ with guesses about context.